# Do Spell-Like Abilities Require Concentration Checks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, concentration

I was wondering, for spell-like abilities, do you need to make concentration checks to cast defensively, if damaged while casting, etc?  Or is none of that necessary, since they technically aren't spells?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Spell-Like Abilities](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Spell-Like%20Abilities) are outlined in the Universal Monster Rules section

> It is possible to attempt a concentration check to use a spell-like ability defensively and avoid provoking attacks of opportunity, just as when casting a spell. A spell-like ability can be disrupted just as a spell can be. Spell-like abilities cannot be used to counterspell, nor can they be counterspelled.

Comment: My brain completely forgot about this and where to find it.   Superior answer to my rambling tidbit.  Ty Ifusaso.